# nhibernate generating incorrect sql query with weird alias

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

So I have An entity called VideoAsset that is mapped to a VideoCategory and Group. Both are many to many:

```
public class VideoAssetMap : IAutoMappingOverride<VideoAsset>
{

    public void Override(AutoMapping<VideoAsset> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Map(x => x.Description)
            .CustomSqlType("NTEXT");

        mapping.HasManyToMany<Group>(x => x.Groups)
            .Table("VideoAssetGroups")
            .ParentKeyColumn("VideoAssetId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("GroupId")
            .AsSet();

        mapping.HasManyToMany<VideoCategory>(x => x.Categories)
            .Table("VideoCategoryRel")
            .ParentKeyColumn("VideoCategoryId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("VideoAssetId")
            .AsSet();
    }

}
```

When I try to run the following query in nunit with sqlite using the following:

```
ICriteria query = this.Session.CreateCriteria<VideoAsset>("a")
            .CreateAlias("a.Categories", "c")
            .CreateAlias("a.Groups", " ag")
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("c.Id", category.Id))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("a.Enabled", true));
```

My sql can't execute because it's broken:

```
inner join Groups alias_ ag2_ on groups4_.GroupId=alias_ ag2_.GroupId
```

I checked my database tables and I don't believe there is anything wrong with them. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a space in your alias of the Groups property.

.CreateAlias("a.Groups", " ag")